# Run cucumber headlessly with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, spork

I have my cucumber tests running fine without Spork using the webkit driver for my javascript scenarios.

I have the following in my env.rb file

```
if(ENV["WEBKIT"])
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
end
```

When I run my features without spork from the terminal

```
WEBKIT=true cucumber
```

The tests run correctly using the webkit driver.  But as soon as I try adding in spork with the --drb option, every javascript feature starts spinning up Firefox again using the Selenium driver.

```
WEBKIT=true cucumber --drb
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out the issue is that the environment variables must be set on the Sport server rather than through Cucumber for them to be picked up.

I am now starting Spork from the terminal like this

```
WEBKIT=true spork cucumber
```

and then starting cucumber with just the --drb flag

```
cucumber --drb
```